# You do not have administrative privileges on the server Failover Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2016, failover, failovercluster

I am trying to setup a 3 node Failover cluster in Azure. The below is my configuration:

Region: West Europe

VM Size: Standard D2s v3

Storage: Premium LRS

Data Disk: 2 numbers, 128 GB

OS Disk: 127 GB, Premium

OS: Windows 2016 DataCenter

3 nodes are domain joined. 1 DC.

Account used is in Domain Admins group. Account is also added to the Local Admins group in each of the nodes. In addition, the account and all descendants have given "Full Control" (for testing purposes) in Domain Controller -> Active Directory -> the domain -> Advanced Features - > Security.

I have tried multiple times, and followed instructions found in forums like rejoin domain, checked access, synced time etc. The weird thing is that I got it working once (though I don't remember any significant changes from other attempts), but since it was late night I stopped all the VMS (the cluster nodes and DC). Next day, I started all VMs to continue the work, only to see that it isn't working anymore. Could someone shed some light on this please?

[image]

Comment: Another possible option to check is to try another account frm the Domain Admins group.

Comment: I have been this type of stuff for 20 years professionally and never came across what you have said. If you are a member of Domain Admins you can do whatever you want. So my conclusion is you have seriously screwed up the permissions somehow when changing them (the bit you said changed). The fact you did that suggests you are not well versed in AD and therefore will not be able to fix this. my advice would be to blow all machines away including DC and start over. DON'T change any permissions, a DA is enough to do what you want.

Comment: @Mucker thanks. Microsoft ticket was opened and they reviewed it multiple times. They also could not figure out what is going on. The ticket had been open for more than one year, escalated every possible levels. I don't know where it stands now as I moved on to a different job! Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue, I RDP the the other NODE that was giving the error, launched Failover Cluster manager and added successfully